# In MVC, how do I setup 2 routes (one with a hardcoded segment, and the other with an empty segment) to point to the same destination?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to setup routes in my MVC application, where one route could have the segment "Portal" and another route has no "Portal" segment at all.  Essentially, I need these URLs to send the user to the same page, but I also want /Home/Index to be the default:

```
/Portal/Home/Index
/Home/Index
```

I have the following code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PortalDefault", // Route name
    "Portal/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, portal = String.Empty } // Parameter defaults
);
```

This allows the user to go to /Portal/Home/Index and /Home/Index but the problem is that the website now defaults to /Portal/Home/Index.

**I need the website to default to /Home/Index but still allow /Portal/Home/Index**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add a route for the home page to override `PortalDefault`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home", // Route name
    "", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", portal = String.Empty } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "PortalDefault", // Route name
    "Portal/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, portal = String.Empty } // Parameter defaults
);
```

> **NOTE:** It seems odd that your `PortalDefault` route doesn't define a route value for `portal`, but your `Default` route does.